# org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access from HandledContributionItem

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin, swt

I know there are lots of such questions here and most of them are answered. But the answers just won't solve my case.

I'm working on an eclipse plugin project, have a customized project type which can be either run or debugged. I have implemented the run and debug function and everything I expected are displayed on the screen, except the console shows an exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2015-04-28 23:31:17.410
!MESSAGE Internal error during tool item enablement updating, this is only       logged once per tool item.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:783)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:574)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getData(Widget.java:874)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.updateIcons(HandledContributionItem.java:546)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.update(HandledContributionItem.java:440)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.update(HandledContributionItem.java:430)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$3.run(HandledContributionItem.java:168)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.updateItemEnablement(HandledContributionItem.java:196)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolItemUpdater.updateContributionItems(ToolItemUpdater.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer$8.changed(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:367)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:352)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService.contextEvaluate(EvaluationService.java:139)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService.addSourceProvider(EvaluationService.java:180)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contexts.DebugContextSourceProvider.<init>(DebugContextSourceProvider.java:51)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contexts.DebugWindowContextService.<init>(DebugWindowContextService.java:62)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contexts.DebugContextManager.createService(DebugContextManager.java:163)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contexts.DebugContextManager.getContextService(DebugContextManager.java:221)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.ViewContextService.<init>(ViewContextService.java:620)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.ViewContextManager.windowOpened(ViewContextManager.java:93)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.ViewContextManager.<init>(ViewContextManager.java:55)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.ViewContextManager.getDefault(ViewContextManager.java:44)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contexts.DebugContextManager.getDefault(DebugContextManager.java:150)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.getDebugContextManager(DebugUITools.java:1068)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.sourcelookup.SourceLookupService.<init>(SourceLookupService.java:40)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.sourcelookup.SourceLookupManager.windowOpened(SourceLookupManager.java:91)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.sourcelookup.SourceLookupManager.<init>(SourceLookupManager.java:41)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.sourcelookup.SourceLookupManager.getDefault(SourceLookupManager.java:53)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.initializeLaunchListeners(DebugUIPlugin.java:935)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.launchAdded(DebugUIPlugin.java:920)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchManager$LaunchNotifier.run(LaunchManager.java:451)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchManager$LaunchNotifier.notify(LaunchManager.java:438)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchManager.fireUpdate(LaunchManager.java:1044)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchManager.addLaunch(LaunchManager.java:708)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:834)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

My codes are as following: In LaunchShortCut.java I have

```java
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      Shell activeShell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
      if(DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialog(activeShell, config, group, null) == Window.CANCEL){
        return;
      }
    }
  });
```

This trigger the LaunchConfigurationWindow, and does not show any exception in console. When I hit the "run" in this window, the process stops at the first line in the following code where I have a breakpoint, and shows the exception in the console.

```java
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //clear old output
    HTMLOutput htmloutput = (HTMLOutput) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView("my.view.id");
  }
}
```

From the stack trace of the exception I don't see anything related to my code. If I let the program go on running, everything is fine, I don't see any trouble this exception causes, but I just can't figure what's it about and can't even stop it from showing up. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you've hit a bug in Eclipse. The same stacktrace is described in [Bug 445560](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445560). Chances are that the workaround described in this bug report (see comment 4) also helps in your case:

> As current local workaround for this issue I've added in our rcp code an early call to DebugUITools.getDebugContextManager()  from the UI thread.
>   Ugly, and should not be needed, but it avoids the failures seen when launching for the first time.